# Redux confirmation before multiple actions

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning Redux with React. I'm trying to display a confirmation alert before proceeding with a series of actions (e.g. a network request).

I don't have a problem displaying the alert itself, but what's a good strategy for determining what happens after the alert is closed, and continuing with my other actions?

I was hoping for some generic approach, so I could dispatch the show-confirmation action in the same function where I define what happens when it's confirmed.

All of the approaches I've seen to this seem to require you to add your on-close handler function to the Redux store, which is not allowed. Or they suggest adding a second action to the store, which the confirmation component will then dispatch. But this doesn't help if I want to call a more complex sequence of actions.

I've also seen suggestions to use redux-saga, but I'm sure something this basic can be done with the standard Redux package, without introducing yet another third-party library. Right?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, yeah I wouldn't add the `onClose` handler to the store. Instead, I would keep track of the modals visibility in the store. Then, each time the modal visibility changes, you would dispatch an action that would update your components with a new value for `isModalVisible` or whatever. You would then have a generic visibility change handler for when your modal gets toggled.

Then in the component, you would use it like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.isModalVisible !== this.props.isModalVisible && !nextProps.isModalVisible) {
        // this.handleModalChange()
        // dispatch any other actions here
    }
}
```

First check to make sure the state has actually changed, and then do a second check to only trigger when the modal closes.

Comment: That sounds like it has potential. Although I think you'd need a different state field for each confirmation dialog, instead of a single `isModalVisible`, so that a component could distinguish its own dialogs from dialogs opened by other components. Maybe it would even make sense to generate a random ID for the dialog, and then watch for that ID in `componentWillReceiveProps`. I'm sure this backwards approach to programming is going to pay off someday, right?

Comment: @JW. Ah, good point. You could use a unique id that describes the modal too, something like `{id: 'edit-user-modal'}, {id: delete-confirm-modal }`.

Comment: Yes.  Please see my post [Practical Redux, Part 10: Managing Modals and Context Menus](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/07/practical-redux-part-10-managing-modals/) for examples of this approach.

Comment: @markerikson I looked at your Color Picker example, which was useful. But it seems like that approach is only capable of dispatching serializable actions after a color is selected. For example, you wouldn't be able to make an `onColorPickedAction` that fires off a network request and handle the results, since that would require it to be a function/thunk. You'd have to combine it with this `componentWillReceiveProps` approach above, along with some unique identifier for the dialog.

Comment: You _could_ certainly put a function in the store for use as a dialog prop.  [We don't _recommend_ that approach](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state), but you can.  If you need more logic to execute when the action is dispatched, this would be a good use case for a side effects middleware like redux-saga, redux-observable, or something similar.